# Hide navbar item after successful Log in in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I would like to hide the following **Login** and **Register** navbar items after successful login:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                 
                    <li><a href="login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="" data-ng-click="logout()">LogOut</a></li>
                    <li><a href="register">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**Here is my Login Controller:**

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$window', 'accountService', '$location', function ($scope, $window, accountService, $location) {

    $scope.loginPageHeader = "Login Page";
    $scope.account = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    }
    $scope.login = function () {
        accountService.login($scope.account).then(function (data) {
            $location.path('/home');
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.message = error.error_description;
        })
    }


    $scope.logout = function () {
        accountService.logout();
        $location.path('/login');
    }

}])
```

**Here is my AccountService:**

```
app.factory('accountService', ['$http', '$q', 'serviceBasePath', 'userService', '$window', function ($http, $q, serviceBasePath, userService, $window) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.login = function (user) {
        var obj = { 'username': user.username, 'password': user.password, 'grant_type': 'password' };
        Object.toparams = function ObjectsToParams(obj) {
            var p = [];
            for (var key in obj) {
                p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
            }
            return p.join('&');
        }

        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: serviceBasePath + "/token",
            data: Object.toparams(obj),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function (response) {
            userService.SetCurrentUser(response.data);
            defer.resolve(response.data);
        }, function (error) {
            defer.reject(error.data);
        })
        return defer.promise;
    }
    fac.logout = function () {
        userService.CurrentUser = null;
        userService.SetCurrentUser(userService.CurrentUser);

    }
    return fac;
}])
```

**Here is my UserService:**

```
app.factory('userService', function () {
    var fac = {};
    fac.CurrentUser = null;
    fac.SetCurrentUser = function (user) {
        fac.CurrentUser = user;
        sessionStorage.user = angular.toJson(user);
    }
    fac.GetCurrentUser = function () {
        fac.CurrentUser = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.user);
        return fac.CurrentUser;
    }
    return fac;
})
```

**Tried with $rootScope but didn't work after page refresh as $rootScope is lost after page refresh. Any Help Please!!**

Comment: `$rootScope` would be a good place to do this. That you lose the information after a refresh is more an issue of loading the user when instantiating the application.

Comment: So how can I retain $rootScope Value even after page refresh??

Comment: By doing a check in the app's `run` function if the user is stored in the session, then setting it on `$rootScope` again

Comment: write the necessary code as answer please!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check in your app's `run` function and set it on the `$rootScope`. This way a reload (f5) doesn't interfere with the login:

```
app.run(["$rootScope", "userService", function($rootScope, userService) {
    var user = userService.GetCurrentUser();
    if (user) {
        $rootScope.user = user;
    }
}]);
```

Then in your view:

```
<li><a href="login" ng-if="!$root.user">Login</a></li>
```

Also mind that you set it on the `$rootScope` when logging in:

```
fac.SetCurrentUser = function (user) {
    fac.CurrentUser = user;
    sessionStorage.user = angular.toJson(user);
    $rootScope.user = user;
}
```

[See jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af761eub/)

Comment: That will most likely cause a racing issue, `userService.GetCurrentUser()` will be called before the async call from `login` is returned

Comment: Why? This only looks if the user is in the sessionStorage, and sets it on the `$rootScope` if it is.

Comment: `SetCurrentUser` is called with `user` data as a result of `$http` call, is it not?

Comment: Yes, on the moment the user actually logs in (typing in username and password). After that it is stored in the sessionStorage, which isn't async. So if the user is not already logged in, the `GetCurrentUser()` will return null, so the `$rootScope.user` won't be set

Comment: Still, it's not called until the `login` method is called so `var user = userService.GetCurrentUser();` might be null, the easiest solution would be two-way data binding between the service and controller

Comment: See added jsfiddle which proves that it works. After login, press f5 and you can see you are still logged in.